# ASP.NET Web API Error, After Trying Assign Interface In Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, interface, controller, repository

Created an interface and a repository for it .. now I'm trying to call it through the controller -> and getting an error across this controller Route..

**ExpenseController.cs**

```
public class ExpenseController : ApiController
{

    private readonly IExpenseRepository _repository;

    public ExpenseController (IExpenseRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

**IExpenseRepository.cs**

```
public interface IExpenseRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Expense> GetExpense(EntityCollection expenseCollection, EntityCollection employeeCollection);
}
```

**ExpenseRepository.cs**

```
public class ExpenseRepository : IExpenseRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Expense> GetExpense(EntityCollection expenseCollection, EntityCollection employeeCollection)
    {
        List<Expense> expenses = new List<Expense>();

        foreach (Entity app in expenseCollection.Entities)
        {
            Expense expense = new Expense();
                ...............
               ...............
            expenses.Add(expense);
        }

        return expenses;
    }
}
```

***{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ExpenseController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Type 'ExpenseBook.Controllers.ExpenseController' does not have a default constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":" at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"}}***

Comment: Are you using any IOC container? you need to tell webapi how to resolve this dependencies (if using .net core ConfigureServices in Startup class , else if using .Net Framework in webapi configuration you need to specify Dependency resolver as IOC container)

Comment: ohhh.. i'm new in this one .. here i using .Net Framework , let's try to add IOC Dependency

Comment: No worries : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection , here hope this link gives you some guidance.

Comment: fixed using Ninject Resolver, thanks for fast answer again ! ;) :)